# aggregate with empty factor but keep row

Tags: r, aggregate

I had a similar questions with by() where I accepted the fact that I had to manually replace the resulting NAs. Now I would like to aggregate my data.frame and keep the structure. e.g. My larger data set has factors for 100 countries * 10 years * 5 segments, so it should reduce to 5000 rows. But sometimes some of the segment factors are empty and i only get <5000 rows. I cannot get my head around it...

My MWE still applies:

```
#All 3 categories are used
df1<-data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:4),3), factor=cut(rep(seq(1:4),3),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))
# Thirds category is not used
df2<-data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:3),4), factor=cut(rep(seq(1:3),4),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))

#df1 reduces to 3 rows as each category is used
aggregate(df1$val,list(df1$factor),sum)
#df2 reduces to 2 rows because C is empty
aggregate(df2$val,list(df2$factor),sum)
#I would like
data.frame(Group.1=LETTERS[1:3], x=c(12,12,0))

  Group.1  x
1       A 12
2       B 12
3       C  0
```

Comment: I always thought that this is what the `drop` argument for... Apparently not

Comment: Funny I actually did not see the drop thing, but from the description I would have thought the same thing now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# create dataset
df2 <- data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:3),4), factor=cut(rep(seq(1:3),4),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))

library(dplyr)

levels(df2$factor) %>%                                    # get distinct levels of the factor variable
  data.frame(factor = .) %>%                              # create a data frame
  left_join(df2 %>%                                       # join with
            group_by(factor) %>%                             # for each value that exists
            summarise(x = sum(val)), by = "factor") %>%      # sum column val
  mutate(x = coalesce(x, 0L))                             # replace NAs with 0s

#   factor  x
# 1      A 12
# 2      B 12
# 3      C  0
```

Or without any package

```
dd = merge(data.frame(Group.1 = levels(df2$factor)), 
           aggregate(df2$val,list(df2$factor),sum), all.x = T)
dd$x = ifelse(is.na(dd$x), 0, dd$x)
dd

#   Group.1  x
# 1       A 12
# 2       B 12
# 3       C  0
```

Or using `data.table` package to check if it's faster

```
library(data.table)

# assuming you start with a data frame
df2 <- data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:3),4), factor=cut(rep(seq(1:3),4),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))

# create a data table with all unique values of the variable "factor" and an index (key) on that variable
dt_levels = data.table(factor = levels(df2$factor), key = "factor")

# make df2 a data table with an index on column "factor" and aggregate
dt_sum = setDT(df2, key = "factor")[, list(Sum = sum(val)), by = "factor"]

# left join the two data tables and replace NA values with 0s
dt_result = dt_sum[dt_levels][, Sum := ifelse(is.na(Sum), 0, Sum)]

dt_result[]

#    factor Sum
# 1:      A  12
# 2:      B  12
# 3:      C   0
```

Comment: This would probably take very long if my data has 4'743'200 rows, wont it?

Comment: Also depends on how many unique values (levels) you have. That will affect the join. Better to try all approaches and pick the faster one in my opinion.

Comment: I like the merge one the most so far. I probably have to do some further microbenchmarking to see which one is the fastest. Actually it seems rather similar to the one proposed by Chase Grimm. I set up my target date frame with expand.grid with my factor levels and then merge it with the aggregate() call

Comment: You prefer it because it's the fastest one so far? When I find time I'll try to post another solution using the data.table package, as @Psidom suggested. This might be faster.

Comment: I prefer it because it was most flexible about the naming of the columns and I ended up using it before the aggregation of my dataset though speed was not an issue anymore. Thx you very much, and the others as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `complete` function from `tidyr` to explicitly show the missing values in the results:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
        group_by(factor) %>% 
        summarise(x = sum(val)) %>% 
        complete(factor, fill = list(x = 0))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#   factor     x
#   <fctr> <dbl>
# 1      A    12
# 2      B    12
# 3      C     0
```

With `aggregate` function:

```
tidyr::complete(aggregate(df2$val,list(df2$factor),sum), Group.1, fill = list(x = 0))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#  Group.1     x
#   <fctr> <dbl>
#1       A    12
#2       B    12
#3       C     0
```

Comment: Thx the tidyr::complete seemed easiest to replicate for me and it worked. as for the other solution it does take almost 20 sec to run with my original data.frame

Comment: I would think the first option would be faster but it doesn't seem like so. 20 secs for me is acceptable unless you are going to production. You could also try a data table version which usually should be faster.

Comment: Is there a way to just set the fill option to zero for all variables without having to name them ? My data set has quite a few columns over which I aggregate, so this would be a bit annoying

Comment: The default fill is `NA`. You can always replace the NA in the data frame with 0 afterwards something like `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`. Or pre-store your columns in a vector like `cols` and then do something like `setNames(list(rep(0, length(cols))), cols)`.

Answer (score 1):

So this is pretty basic, but I just made a new data frame with 2 columns. 
One with each factor level, and one with all 0.  Then I used `rbind` to but my new frame and df2 together, and then used aggregate.

```
df2 <- data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:3),4), factor=cut(rep(seq(1:3),4),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))

dat <- data.frame(val = 0, factor = levels(df2$factor))

df3 <- rbind(df2,dat)

aggregate(. ~ factor,df3,sum)

#  factor val
#1      A  12
#2      B  12
#3      C   0
```